# how to build a stable API product and allow specification per project?

Tags: git, api

I am in search of information on how I to manage code in git flow and methodology to test and work with it :

- I have an API in place to build and manage a product catalog and it was designed around the business needs of my first client project (let's call this the master branch)
- For a second project with another client , I have deliver initially the same API, but after some exchange with  this new client, the interface of my API need to evolve and introduce a new version of the API.
- I'd like to have a main base API as a base for my future others projects so I am wondering how could I merge  and evolve my API by incorporating the various contract breaking changes in a single master branch...

Not sure if I am clear in my question : but the fact is as now, for every new projects that I am dealing with, I first start to analyse the need of my client and chose to start from the branch that seem the closer to their needs : in the end I have as many branches and specialisation as clients... It's not maintenable anymore... So please give advice and strategy on modeling and git flow branching...

Comment: This calls for more existential questions like: "am I a dev shop delivering one-off tailor-made solutions, or a software company selling a cohesive product with its own trajectory, culture, boundaries etc.?" Not always easy to decide :)

Comment: In fact we want to make a cohesive product but I need advices on how to organize and managed my different apis....

Answer (score 3):

Generally what you are considering doing is thought to be a bad idea.

The problem is that you end up with multiple versions of the same program, all of which are slightly different and require maintaining.

Although source control programs like Git seem like they can cope with this, either using forks or branches, in practice once the versions diverge to the point where you have features on one that you dont want on the other. The system breaks down, and you essentially have two copies of the code base.

The correct approach is to introduce a plugin architecture to your application and develop features on separate repositories as plugins while keeping a single main application.

Having said that, there are plenty of big companies that maintain multiple versions of the same product for different clients. Just dont try and trick yourself into thinking you will be able to merge bug fixes across all your versions with a mouse click, while keeping the features different.

Comment: How can this plugin architecture could work for my apis?